# I can't write to txt file which is added into project

Tags: c#, filestream

31/12/2014
SOLUTION: change filename = @"../../text.txt" 
I did it successfully ^^ Thank you so much

---

If my text file is determined by a path, for example filename = "C:\text.txt", I can write data into that file normally.

But if I add text.txt (determined by filename = "text.txt") into my C# project, my program still run without error but nothing is written into text.txt file

Besides I can read txt file (with filename = "text.txt") normally.

Did I miss something? Please help me!

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append);
StreamWriter writeRecord = new StreamWriter(stream);

writeRecord.Write("Random string");
writeRecord.WriteLine();            

writeRecord.Close(); 
stream.Close();
```

Edit: Sorry Sorry. I also mean that When i added text.txt into C# project. I open file with FileMode.Append and write but data in text.txt file, which i added into project, didn't change

Thank you Kennyzx!
I have checked. I really have file text there, but I also i have another text file at [nameproject]\ that i added into project before didn't change

Comment: have you checked the output folder of the program (.\bin\Debug)? text.txt should have been created there.

Comment: Sorry Sorry. I also mean that When i added text.txt into C# project. I open file with FileMode.Append and write but data in text.txt file, which i added into project, isn't changed

Comment: so what you want is updating the file in your project? not the file in the Debug folder?

Comment: this requirement is abnormal. Because your program can be copied to anywhere else and executed, without an absolute path like "C:\Users\...\desktop\Myproject\text.txt", you program can never find the text file in the project.

Comment: OK, i see what is problem, you think that text.txt is the file in your project, that is, relative to your project folder, but actually the file path is relative to where the program is located (bin\Debug). If you _**really**_ want that, you can try filename="..\..\text.txt"

Comment: How can you explain that I can read that file normally> I just can't write anything into that file!

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the complete file path and file name when specifying the file to open.
Rather than "text.txt" use "C:\YourProjectPath\YourTextFolder\text.txt"

Answer (score 0):

Select the text file in your project.  Then look in the property window (F4 will show it if you don't have it docked anywhere) for 'Copy to output Directory' and change it from 'Do not copy' to either 'Copy always' or 'Copy if newer'.

After doing this you can read the file using just "text.txt".

Comment: yes, i changed it from 'copy if newer'. I can read, but the problem is that i can't write

Comment: Oh, your program runs from {ProjectName}\bin\Debug.  The exact path will vary based on your build configuration.  If you want to edit the file in the project not the one copied to the build location then try using "../../text.txt" for the filename.  Again this may need to be modified based on your build configuration.